# How to send array with json using ajax

Tags: json, ajax

How do I send an array with json using ajax? I want to store email and name:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=module/newsletters/news',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'email=' + $('#txtemail').val() ,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        alert(json.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose you have an array?

```
var array = [
    "student1" : {
        "name": "jon",
        "email": "test@example.com"
    },
    "student2" : {
        "name": "jon2",
        "email": "test2@example.com"
    }
]


$.post('index.php?route=module/newsletters/news', {
    data : JSON.stringify(array),
    datatype : 'application/json',
}, function(success) {
    console.log(success)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.please write your question in correct format.then community can be resolve your question easily.

I assume your problem and give solution for that.

```
var array = {name:'dua',email:'dua@gmail.com'};

$.post('index.php?route=module/newsletters/news', {
    data : JSON.stringify(array)
}, function(success) {
    console.log(success)
});
```

Comment: i have a subscribe button and call return subscribe() onclick event now only one field email is store in database i want to store name also how can i do this using this method

Comment: i want this 
array(1) {
  ["email"]=>
  "dua@hotmail.com "
}
array(2) {
  ["name"]=>
  "dua "
}

Comment: you can combined those two array into one and use above code section to post data to serverside

Answer (score 0):

var postData =  { "email":email,"name":name }

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=module/newsletters/news',
                    type: 'post',

                     data: postData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(json) {
                    alert(json.message);

                    }

                });
```